# Deriving Bayes risk for squared error loss function

Tags: self-study, bayesian

I think I must be doing something wrong here because my derived Bayes Risk is incredibly long and cumbersome...

Let $X|p \sim Bin(n,p)$ and $p \sim Beta(a,b)$.

Then $p|X \sim Beta(a+x,b+n-x)$ and the Bayes estimator of $p$ is given by

$$\delta(X) = \frac{a+x}{a+b+n}$$

My goal is to derive the Bayes risk of the Bayes estimator $\delta (X)$. My textbook seems to define (it's not actually clear to me...) Bayes risk under the squared error loss function as

$$E_{X,p} (\delta(X) - p)^2$$

which, I think, we can derive sequentially using the law of total expectation

$$E (\delta(X) - p)^2 = E[ E[(\delta(X) - p)^2|p]]$$

So my attempt to derive Bayes risk has first been to derive

$$E[(\delta(X) - p)^2|p]$$

Using the fact that $X |p \sim bin(n,p)$ and then, after deriving that, finding the total expectation by using $p \sim beta(a,b)$.

However intuitively I think I must be wrong, as the final Bayes risk I arrive at is incredibly long and tedious... and I don't think the textbook would give a problem with such a messy answer.

Is this wrong? And if not, is there any easier way to derive it in this situation?

I looked for similar answers on here for deriving Bayes risk and amazingly couldn't find any other than ddiscussions on the meaning of Bayes risk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decomposition you propose is correct:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} (\delta(X) - p)^2 &= \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[(\delta(X) - p)^2|p]]\\
&= \mathbb{E}[ \underbrace{\text{var}_p(\delta(X)) + (\mathbb{E}[\delta(X)]-p)^2}_\text{Pythegorean theorem}]\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{np(1-p)}{(a+b+n)^2}+\left( \frac{a+np}{a+b+n}-p\right)^2\right]\\
&=\frac{A\mathbb{E}[p^2]+B\mathbb E[p] +C}{(a+b+n)^2}
\end{align*}
from which you should be able to extract a rather simple expression by recovering $A,B,C$ from the decomposition of the squares. If not, the example is processed in my book, [The Bayesian Choice](http://amzn.to/2kxykkw) [Examples 4.4 and 4.5].

Comment: Thanks Xi'an, that's indeed what I ended up at using $MSE = Var + Bias^2$. So for the final step, the expectation of $p$ is simply taken with respect to the marginal prior distribution $p \sim Beta(a,b)$, correct? The expression I end up at is quite messy, but perhaps I can simplify it a bit

Comment: Also thanks for the book recommendation. I've been after a good Bayesian book to read similar to Casella's on inference.

Comment: I see now, thanks, Grouping terms before substituting in $E[p/p^2]$ makes it a lot simpler.

Comment: Hello I tried to look for the example 4.4 and 4.5 in your book The Bayesian Choice, but there seem to be no example 4.4 and 4.5 in Chapter 4 of the book.